# Repository methods for query children of aggregate root

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

I have `Order` aggregate root class containing children value objects:

```
  class Order {
      val id: String
      val lines: Seq[OrderLine]
      val destination: Destination
      //...omit other fields
    }
```

This is a CQRS read model, that is represented by `order-search` microservice responsible for searching orders by some filter.

There is `OrderApplicationService` that uses `OrderRepository` (I am not sure that it is a pure repository in ddd terms):

```
trait OrderRepository {      
  def search(filter:OrderFilter):Seq[Order]      
  def findById(orderId:String):Order      
}
```

and `ElasticSearchOrderRepository` which uses ES as search engine.

Due to new requirements I need new api method for UI that will search for the all destinations across the orders by some filter. It should be `/destinations` endpoint, that will call repository to find all data. The performance is important in this case, so to search for all orders and that map them to `destination` doesn't seem a good solution.

What is the most appropriate option to solve this? :

1. Add new method in `OrderRepository`  e.g. `def searchOrderDestinations(filter:DestinationFilter): Seq[Destination]`
2. Create new repository:

```
    trait OrderDestinationRepository {
      def searchOrderDestinations(filter:DestinationFilter): Seq[Destination]
    }
```

The same is for application service - do I need to create new `DestinationAppService`?

Are these options applicable? Or maybe there is some better solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are querying Orders to retrieve a list of Destinations. I would say that since an Order owns the relationship to Destination, it would be best to add this to your Order Repository and Service. What are your concerns though?

Answer (score 1):

> This is a CQRS read model

Perfect - create and update a list of your orders indexed by destination, and use that to serve the query results.

Think "relational database that includes the data you need to create the view, and an index".  Queries go to the database, which acts as a cache for the information.  A background process (async) runs to update the information in database.

How often you run that process will depend on how stale the data in the view can be.  How bad is it for the business if the view shows results as of 10 minutes ago? as of 1 minute ago? as of an hour ago?

Comment: Yeah, make sense.
But what to do with such cases in general? When I don't need the whole aggregate root but only part of its data. E.g. I can apply some projections to reduce load on db or ES. Let's say I don't want to fetch all orders. Is it good to fetch only entity children (not the whole entity) in the same repository?